# ASCII char to hexa value in C#

Tags: c#

How to convert ASCII char values example `'a'` to its eqvelent hexa value `41` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToInt32(letter));`

Answer (score 3):

Convert to int then to hex

```
Convert.ToInt32('a').ToString("X");
```

`a` is actually `61`, and `A` is `41`

Answer (score 3):

C# has a built in function to convert to byte :  **Convert.ToByte('a')**